# simple cursor adapter query

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I have created a SimpleCursorAdapter. I would like a way to compare two rows. 
lets say the columns are called realData pracData. If i want to compare two columns how would I write the statement to achieve this.

Below is my code for my SimpleCursorAdapter

```
  db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

 //   db.insertContact("how do you print hello world", "print 'hello world';", "print hello", "hello", 1);

  //  db.insertContact("what is x=2 and y=5", "5", "7", "2", 2);
    db.close();

    /*
     *  Open the same SQLite database
     *  and read all it's content.
     */
    db = new DBAdapter(this);
     db.open();

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllContacts();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.question, DBAdapter.possibleAnsOne};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.label, R.id.TextView01};

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);

    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    db.close();
```

This is from the ArrayAdapter

```
if (s.startsWith("how do you print hello world") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
                || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plus);
```

I want to do something similar but compare two rows in my database.

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter  {
private Context context;
private int layout;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
          // do your magic inhere :) the cursor will be at the correct row position
        System.out.println("please select a cursor");
        // int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(People.NAME);
       //  ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
       //     ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
         int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.question);
         System.out.println("What is the column index" +nameCol);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the SimpleCursorAdapter and overriding bindView should work. I usually extend CursorAdapter, but try something à la

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
          TextView label = view.findViewById(R.id.yourid);
          // and then do something with cursor.getString(columnindex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can the task that i am trying to achieve be done with a SimpleCursorAdapter or should I use the cursorAdapter

Comment: hold on, you updated your question, now you want to compare two rows? and earlier in your question, you say you want to compare two columns. Which is it? (you obviously can do both, but the solutions will be different)